# What is the Julia way to dot product over desired dimensions

Tags: multidimensional-array, julia

I have a xy-grid with two vector fields `u` and `v`. I represent vector fields as `Array{Float64, 3}` with dimensions `nx` × `ny` × `2`.
I would like to have dot product `u.v` as a scalar field (`Array{Float64,2}` with dimensions `nx`×`ny`). What is the best way to achieve that?

It would be perfect to have something like `dot(u,v,3)`, where 3 is the dimension over which the dot product is taken.

```
nx, ny = 3, 4

u = Array{Float64,3}(rand(0:1, nx, ny, 2))
#[0.0 1.0 0.0 1.0; 1.0 0.0 1.0 0.0; 1.0 0.0 1.0 0.0]
#[1.0 0.0 1.0 0.0; 1.0 0.0 0.0 1.0; 1.0 0.0 1.0 1.0]

v = Array{Float64,3}(rand(0:1, nx, ny, 2))
#[1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0; 0.0 1.0 0.0 0.0; 0.0 1.0 1.0 0.0]
#[1.0 0.0 0.0 0.0; 0.0 1.0 0.0 0.0; 1.0 1.0 1.0 0.0]

[dot(u[i,j,:], v[i,j,:]) for i in 1:nx, j in 1:ny]

3×4 Array{Float64,2}:
 1.0  1.0  0.0  1.0
 0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
 1.0  0.0  2.0  0.0
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`squeeze(sum(u .* v, 3), 3)` is clean and simple, but if you need more speed, this is approximately 20x times faster on my pc:

```
a = fill(zero(eltype(u)), nx, ny)
@inbounds for k in indices(u, 3)
    for j in indices(u, 2)
        for i in indices(u, 1)
            a[i, j] += u[i, j, k] * v[i, j, k]
        end
    end
end
```

**Edit:** For easier benchmarking comparison, this try this code:

```
function dotsum3(u, v)
    a = fill(zero(eltype(u)), size(u, 1), size(u, 2))
    @inbounds for k in indices(u, 3)
        for j in indices(u, 2)
            for i in indices(u, 1)
                a[i, j] += u[i, j, k] * v[i, j, k]
            end
        end
    end
    return a
end
```

Also note that, if using `@inbounds`, one should probably explicitely check that the sizes of `u` and `v` are compatible.

Comment: Once again, one has to love Julia... You can do it as simple as in Python but if you want speed, just implement a couple of loops. Updated my answer.

Comment: On 0.6.3 seeing only a 1.25x improvement (benchmarking using `@btime`), what is the version and what are the benchmark details on your setup?

Comment: I'm on version 0.6.2. Runtime for @crstnbr's suggestion is 1.676us on my computer, while my code takes 85ns. My guess is that `nx` and `ny` are globals in your function `f1`. Try with `size(u, ...)` instead.

Answer (score 5):

`sum(u.*v,3)` is both (reasonably) fast and short.

To explicity get a matrix you can squeeze the third dimension like so `squeeze(sum(u.*v,3), 3)`

**Update:** Of course, this has allocations and is not the *best* answer if speed is everything. In this case, see @DNF's direct loop implementation which is basically as fast as you can get it.

Answer (score 1):

Another version is

```
a = copy(view(u,:,:,1))
a .*= view(v,:,:,1)
a .+= @views u[:,:,2].*v[:,:,2]
```

Which is easily extensible to arbitrary 3rd dimension length. The benchmarks from my machine:

```
julia> using BenchmarkTools

julia> function f1(u,v)
       a = fill(zero(eltype(u)), nx, ny)
       @inbounds for k in indices(u, 3)
           for j in indices(u, 2)
               for i in indices(u, 1)
                   a[i, j] += u[i, j, k] * v[i, j, k]
               end
           end
       end
       return a
       end
f1 (generic function with 1 method)

julia> f2(u,v) = squeeze(sum(u .* v, 3), 3)
f2 (generic function with 1 method)

julia> function f3(u,v)
       a = copy(view(u,:,:,1))
       a .*= view(v,:,:,1)
       a .+= @views u[:,:,2].*v[:,:,2]
       return a
       end
f3 (generic function with 1 method)

julia> nx, ny = 3, 4
(3, 4)

julia> u = Array{Float64,3}(rand(0:1, nx, ny, 2));

julia> v = Array{Float64,3}(rand(0:1, nx, ny, 2));
```

Timing results:

```
julia> @btime f1($u,$v);   # DNF suggestion
  1.016 μs (1 allocation: 176 bytes)

julia> @btime f2($u,$v);   # original answer
  1.263 μs (14 allocations: 816 bytes)

julia> @btime f3($u,$v);   # this answer
  168.591 ns (5 allocations: 432 bytes)
```

The suggested version is faster (which is logical considering memory ordering of Julia Arrays).

Comment: To make `f3` use any 3rd dimension size, just replace the appropriate line with `@inbounds for i=1:size(u,3) a .+= @views u[:,:,i].*v[:,:,i] ; end`. Benchmarks stay about the same

Comment: Thank you! However, with larger array sizes (`nx=ny=1500`), I got something like this from my machine: `f1→7 ms`, `f2→13 ms`, `f3→11 ms`